# What is the correct way of running sample OSDK app?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to run the sample OSDK app, but I face the following error. I have installed everything correctly, but I think the activation has a problem. This is the error output:

> pi@raspberrypi:/share/dji/Onboard-SDK/build/bin $ `sudo ./djiosdk-flightcontrol-sample UserConfig.txt`
> Read App ID
> User Configuration read successfully.
>
> STATUS/1 @ init, L55: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyS0 with baudrate 230400...
> STATUS/1 @ init, L65: ...Serial started successfully.
> STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L706: Device Serial No. = (removed)
> STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L708: Hardware = A3
> STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L709: Firmware = 3.3.8.47
> ERRORLOG/1 @ initVirtualRC, L1067: Virtual RC is not supported on this
> platform!
> STATUS/1 @ activate, L1277: version 0x303082F
> STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: activate
> STATUS/1 @ getCommonErrorCodeMessage, L722: ACK_NO_RESPONSE_ERROR
> ERRORLOG/1 @ activate, L1302: Failed to activate please retry SET 0x0 ID 0x0 code 0xFFFF
> STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: initVehicle
> STATUS/1 @ getCommonErrorCodeMessage, L722: ACK_NO_RESPONSE_ERROR
> ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L407: Port closed.
> ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L411: Open Protocol cmd send failed, send_len: -1 packet_len: 19
> STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: reset
> STATUS/1 @ getCommonErrorCodeMessage, L722: ACK_NO_RESPONSE_ERROR
> Vehicle not initialized, exiting.

Comment: Is the remote control switched on?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, a few things to try.

1. Do you have internet connection? You need internet at least once to register the app and afterwards it should be cached in memory (at least that's how the mobile sdk works).
2. Did you place your api key in the UserConfig.txt file?
3. When you created the api key did you make sure to choose Onboard SDK and not Mobile or Payload SDK?
4. Is Lightbridge connected and do you have the proper Baud rate set in the UserConfig.txt file?